# How to fetch dynamic JSON

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json, cocoa-touch

I am trying to fetch the `JSON` below, as it's tags are all dynamic (not fixed). I don't know how to fetch them properly.

```
{
  Level1: {
    row1: {
      1: "on",
      2: "off",
      3: "off",
      4: "on",
      5: "on",
      6: "on",
      7: "on",
      8: "on",
      9: "on",
      10: "on",
      11: "on",
      12: "on",
      13: "on",
      14: "on",
      15: "on",
      16: "on",
      17: "on",
      18: "on",
      19: "on",
      20: "on",
      attr: {
        total: "20",
        type: "Gold"
      }
    },
    row10: {
      1: "on",
      2: "on",
      3: "on",
      4: "on",
      5: "on",
      6: "on",
      7: "on",
      8: "on",
      9: "on",
      10: "on",
      11: "on",
      12: "on",
      13: "on",
      14: "on",
      15: "on",
      16: "on",
      17: "on",
      18: "on",
      19: "on",
      20: "on",
      attr: {
        total: "20",
        type: "Bronze"
      }
    }
  },
  Level3: {
    row1: {
      1: "on",
      2: "on",
      3: "on",
      4: "on",
      5: "on",
      6: "on",
      7: "on",
      8: "on",
      9: "on",
      10: "on",
      11: "on",
      12: "on",
      13: "on",
      14: "on",
      15: "on",
      16: "on",
      17: "on",
      18: "on",
      19: "on",
      20: "on",
      attr: {
        total: "20",
        type: "Gold"
      }
    },
    row5: {
      1: "on",
      2: "on",
      3: "on",
      4: "on",
      5: "on",
      6: "on",
      7: "on",
      8: "on",
      9: "on",
      10: "on",
      11: "on",
      12: "on",
      13: "on",
      14: "on",
      15: "on",
      16: "on",
      17: "on",
      18: "on",
      19: "on",
      20: "on",
      attr: {
        total: "20",
        type: "Bronze"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem with this is that in this number of levels, rows and inside it also are dynamic things. In this I need to fetch the on/off values of all rows, level vise. How can I achieve this?

This is what I tried so far:

```
for (NSString *key in [self.mGetDataDict allKeys]) {
    NSLog(@"Accessing .... %@", key);
    level = key;
    for (NSString *rowKey in self.mGetDataDict[key]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", rowKey);
        [arrRows addObject:rowKey];
        for (NSString *valueKey in self.mGetDataDict[key][rowKey]) {
            // NSLog(@"%@ -> %@", valueKey, self.mGetDataDict[key][rowKey][valueKey]);
            if ([valueKey isEqualToString:@"attr"]) {
                dictRow = self.mGetDataDict[key][rowKey][valueKey];
            }
        }
        NSLog(@"--------ROW OVER------------%@\n", dictRow);
        [arrSeats addObject:[dictRow valueForKey:@"total"]];
        [arrType addObject:[dictRow valueForKey:@"type"]];
        NSLog(@"--------seats in row------------%@\n", arrSeats);

        NSString *row = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [arrSeats objectAtIndex:0]];
        rows = [row integerValue];
    }
    NSString *num = [arrSeats valueForKeyPath: @"@sum.self"];
    tot = [num integerValue];
    [arrTot addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", tot]];
    tot = 0;
    [arrSeats removeAllObjects];
    NSLog(@"--------ROW OVER tot seats------------%@\n", arrTot);
    NSLog(@"--------------------seats:%@\n", num);
    NSLog(@"--------------------\n");
}
```

Comment: @kgdesouz please check what i have tried so far.

Comment: Have you looked at Apple's built in `NSJSONDeserializer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
var json_data = {your_data_json};
for (var level_index in json_data){
//level_index - level values like level1, level3
//json_data[level_index] - to get value object, i mean row1{}
    for (var row_index in json_data[level_index]){
    //row_index as row1 or row10, ....
        for (var record_index in json_data[level_index][row_index]){
            if (record_index == "attr"){
            //you r in attr {} object
            }
            else { 
            //getting
            // record_index 1,2,3,....
            //json_data[level_index][row_index][record_info] - on, on, on,.........
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you will need to do is to get that response into an object (in your case an NSDictionary) and then enumerate through the keys to parse it out.  This is easy to do:

You will probably want to use the NSDictionary method - `enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:`

Here is the class reference:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html